# which better unclickable or clickable images

Tags: image, blogger, clickable

are there difference between unclickable or clickable images?
for example page load time and another things because I see people use them
So I was wondering which one is better

Answer (score 1):

unclickable images give you a better page load time, if you want a page to load fast make them unclickable since page load times really influence for example customers when buying stuff online.

please see :
https://smallbiztrends.com/2019/02/page-load-speed-impacts-buying-decisions.html